# createItem for qx.ui.mobile.list.List

Tags: qooxdoo

qx.ui.mobile.list.List seems not to support the qx.data.controller.List.
Is there another way to add a delegate for createItem? I tried to add the create delegation on both classes, but createItem was not invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, how to use databinding with lists:

```
/**
 * Creates a list and returns it.
 */
__createListDataBindings : function() {
  var self = this;

  var list = new qx.ui.mobile.list.List({
  configureItem : function(item, data, row)
    {
      var stopCount = self.getListData().getLength()-row;
      item.setTitle("Stop #"+stopCount);
      item.setSubtitle(data);
    }
  });
  this.bind("listData", list, "model");

  return list;
},
```

ListData is a class property:

```
 properties :
  {
    // overridden
    listData :
    {
      init : new qx.data.Array(),
      nullable : true,
      event : "updateListData"
    }
  },
```

Comment: I meant the createItem delegation mentioned on http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.6/pages/data_binding/controller.html.
But after looking into the code, I think it must be 'createItemRenderer' instead of 'createItem'.
    var delegate = {
    configureItem : function(item) {
      item.setPadding(3);
    },
    createItemRenderer : function() {
      return new qx.ui.mobile.form.CheckBox();
    },
  };sdfsdf